# WebView's scroll distance from top

Tags: android, webview

I am building an android app with a `WebView` in the `MainActivity` wrapped inside a swipe refresh layout.

Now what I want to do is if the webview is scrolled down (even a small distance), I want to hide the swipe refresh layout. And if the webview is not scrolled, i.e., its content is at the top, I want to show the swipe refresh layout.

This is because if the webview is scrolled, it causes a problem that when I scroll up, the swipe refresh layout gets called and doesn't let the webview to scroll up.

I have tried this:

```
final int content_height = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
          if(scrollY!=content_height) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
          else {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: Call `setNestedScrollingEnabled (true)` on the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
      if(scrollY == 0) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      else {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
 }
});
```

Comment: But it would lead to disabling everything on the screen as the webview is in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`